# Redirect to another subdomain unless viewing a directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site which has recently been moved behind a load balancer. This wasn't an issue until my client tried to use certain functions which take a long time to complete - this apparently hits the load balancer's timeout and the action fails. I know that ideally the functions would be rewritten to run faster, or using a background process, but the client isn't willing to pay for this right now so a workaround was devised.

I was able to create a URL that goes directly to the server's IP, bypassing the load balancer, but I don't want general users to be able to access the site from this URL. As such, I'm trying to create an .htaccess rule that 301s the user to the site's main URL unless they view it from the admin page. From what I can tell, the correct format should be:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} bypass.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [r=301,L]
```

That should, by my understanding:

- If the user is on bypass.mydomain.com
- And the URI visited does not start with "admin"
- Forward the user from bypass.mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com

This doesn't seem to be working, however. Instead, it forwards every time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may already checked this but do you have any .htaccess file working? If not, this could be caused by the allowoverride parameter. [See the doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/fr/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

Alexis

Comment: Hi Alexis. The .htaccess is working (there are other .htaccess rules which are functioning as expected). I was able to resolve the issue using the following code:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} bypass\.mydomain\.com
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]+\ /admin
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.com$1 [R,L]`

I have no idea why this works, however. The code was written by our server administrator, who has much more experience than I on these matters, but even he said he wasn't quite sure why this was necessary.